# Ext.Form.DateField disable EditField to just use the Button

Tags: extjs

I am creating an Ext.Form.DateField like this

```
var datepicker2 = new Ext.form.DateField({
        format: 'd.m.Y',
        fieldLabel: 'Bis',
        //width:190,
        value: '01.11.2011',
        allowBlank: false,
        disabledDays: null,
        enableKeyEvents: true,
        forceSelection: true,
        listeners:{
            select:{
                fn:function(combo, value) {
                    //alert("select");
                    messungenObject.timeFilter.upperBoundary = value;
                    messungenObject.updateFilter();
                }
            },
            change:{
                fn:function(combo, value) {
                    //alert("select");
                    messungenObject.timeFilter.upperBoundary = value;
                    messungenObject.updateFilter();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

My question is, how to disable the TextField, so that the user can only set the date by using the button on the right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

from documentation:
editable : Boolean
False to prevent the user from typing text directly into the field; the field can only have its value set via selecting a value from the picker. In this state, the picker can also be opened by clicking directly on the input field itself.

Defaults to: true

No comments. Click to add